# UIViewController.View.Window is null in ViewDidLoad method

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

Regardless on which controller type (`UIViewController`, `UITableViewController`), the following line always yields `null` in the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
this.View.Window
```

Is this behavior normal, or am I doing something odd? What could lead to `UIViewController.View.Window` being `null`?

(I suppose this question concerns not only MonoTouch, but also 'normal' Objective-C Cocoa).

(MonoTouch 5.2.11, Xcode 4.2.1 4D502)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the documentation of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW55), the `window` property is `nil` if the view has not yet been added to a window which is the case when `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: What method is called after the view is added to a window?

Comment: @AlexRyan You can use `-viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 7):

`self.view.window` will be available in **viewDidAppear**:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    print(self.view.window)
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `self.view.window` use

```
[(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]
```

Comment: It's a problem if you are using `UIScene`.

Answer (score 0):

If using `UIScene` you can get the window from `viewWillAppear` like this:

```
    func windowByParent(vc: UIViewController) -> UIWindow? {
        var window: UIWindow? = nil
        var parent: UIViewController? = vc
        
        while parent != nil && window == nil {
            window = parent?.view.window
            parent = parent?.parent
        }
        return window
    }
```