# How could a tableview.window is nil when i use tableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i wanna add a collectionView on the top of all the views in a tableViewController, so i used the code below in viewDidAppear

```
tableView.window?.addSubview(selectedView) 
tableView.window?.bringSubview(toFront: selectedView)
```

strangely, i couldnt saw the view as i supposed, and as i

```
po tableView.window
```

in the terminal, the answer is 'nil'

but the most strange thing is that the same code worked in another tableViewController

BTW: I knew the best way is using UIViewController to replace UITableViewController, but i just wanna know how could tableView.window is nil in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear when using a UITableViewController

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278204/uiviewcontroller-view-window-is-null-in-viewdidload-method   this question told that window will be nil when view havnt been added to the superView when viewDidLoad called, but how could this happen on a tableViewController with tableView?

Comment: In my case warning was caused by animated reload of data source in viewWillAppear(animated:): dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)