# Migrating old Xcode project to new one with UISceneDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, uiapplication, uiscenedelegate

I have an old Xcode project without `UISceneDelegate` methods. Is it possible to migrate an old Xcode project to a new one with `UISceneDelegate` methods BUT still maintaining compatibility with iOS 12?

If so, how? Because I see a lot of bugs in iOS 14 for which the only workaround is using UISceneDelegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT 1:

Make sure you query for `windowOrientation`, after View Controller's view is rendered. Typically in `viewDidLoad()` and `viewWillAppear(_:)`, `view.window` is `nil`, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278204/uiviewcontroller-view-window-is-null-in-viewdidload-method#answer-10278272). Just check value for `windowOrientation` in `viewDidAppear(_:)`.

If you have some issues to access this value even before try the following definition

```
private var windowOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation ?? .unknown
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    }
}
```

I am not sure if your app uses multiple windows or not but if there is only one(since you are not creating any window programatically), the following definition should work fine.

```
var hasTopNotch: Bool {
    return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0 > 20
}
```

#### Original Answer:

`UISceneDelegate` has been introduced in `iOS 13.0` so no way to be compatible with `iOS 12`, you need to depend on `UIApplicationDelegate` totally. To support `UISceneDelegate` in for `iOS 13.x`, you need to add explicit availability checking to avoid compilation error.

#### Steps 1: Add Scene Manifest in `Info.plist`

Open `Info.plist` as `Source Code` and add the following

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>Default Configuration</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                <string>Main</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

#### Step 2: Create `SceneDelegate.swift` file with the following content

```
import UIKit
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }


}
```

#### Step 3: Update `AppDelegate`

1. Add  `UISceneSession Lifecycle` methods.

```
// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}
```

ii) Finally refer to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle). You may refer to https://dev.to/kevinmaarek/add-a-scene-delegate-to-your-current-project-5on for additional clean up and setup tasks.

Comment: Looking at the code, I believe this code should work on iOS 13 and above and most importantly not impact anything on devices running iOS12, correct?

Comment: `impact anything on devices running iOS12, correct` Sorry to say that I do not have a device running iOS 12.x, since you are targeting that, I guess you have one. Please test it on real devices to make it production ready.

Comment: view.window?.windowScene? is coming out to be nil after adding the code. Anything I missed to add?

Comment: Actually, view.window is nil in rootViewController after loading.

Comment: Can you put a break point in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` and run `po window`? There should be some value in `iOS13.0` where as in AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it will be `nil`.

Comment: It's not nil in the scene delegate function, but it's nil in UIApplicationDelegate as well as UIViewController's view.window. How to extract window in UIViewController?

Comment: How and when does SceneDelegate window gets set? I need to determine interfaceOrientation in UIViewController. This code used to work in every UIViewController previously....   private var windowOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation{ return view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation ?? .unknown }

Comment: I tested it on an old project with a single view controller, I can see I am getting value for it. Can you do the same for the very first view controller you are landed. Also please check that you are not allocating any `window` programatically. If so, please also try to set it using `UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene = <your scene delegate UIScene as? UIWindowScene>` . But not sure about this approach.

Comment: I don't allocate any custom window. Have old storyboard. Does anything need to be updated there as well?

Comment: Can you put a break point in `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)` and try to check `po view.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation`?

Comment: Ok I see it is nil in viewDidLoad. That doesn't seem to be the origin of the problem though. My code relies on lot of custom layouts based on portrait/landscape modes and it is broken now. Not sure what could change by moving to UISceneDelegate

Comment: I found the problem and notice a difference in behavior with/without UISceneDelegate. Although it may not be related to this question, I have updated the question.